# Why my getBoundingClientRect() function doesn't take the right misure of my svg in the accordion?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, accordion, getboundingclientrect

I made some charts with the d3.js library and to do that I've always used the function `element.node().getBoundingClientRect()` to take the width and the height from the svg that I've created on the HTML. Now i took some code from others to make an accordion and I need to create my chart in the div that disappear. The problem is that when I checked the function mentioned before I discoverd that it returns 0 for both width and height of the container.

This my HTML

```html
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingFour">
  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-    target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
    <span>Content</span>
  </button>
</h2>
<div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-body middle-align linechart-container-accordion">
    <svg id="accordion-chart"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my JavaScript

```js
function filledLineChart(ID)
{
    let svg = d3.select("#" + ID),

    let svgObject = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect(),
         width = svgObject.width,
         height = svgObject.height;

    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
}
```

Comment: is the svg a descendant of something that's display: none

Comment: I hadn't write the code for the accordion, so I don't really know, but when clicking on the button the div that you have under the button appear and disappear, but I don't if there's a "display: none" and whatever, it should change after clicking on it